# Mock Python async multi function

Tags: python, async-await, microservices, tornado

How to mock async multi-function in python tornado framework. I want to do unit testing for the async function. inside the async function, I have an await multi() function call. how do I patch this multi-function for unit testing?

```
from tornado.gen import multi

async def get_session_details(request_param, docs):
     sesson = await multi([doc for doc in docs])
     # session result is [[],[],[],[],[]]
     return session

# unit test
import pytest
from tornodo.gen import multi
import mock

@mock.patch(tornoda.gen.multi)
async def test_get_session(mock_multi)
    mock_multi.return_value = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    session = get_session_detals(request_param, docs)
    assert session[0][session] is None

# The above code I tried but mock multi is not patching with get_session_details.
```

Comment: share your code which you have tried .

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

**mocker.patch("tornodo.gen.tornodo.gen.multi", return_value = [[],[],[],[],[]])**

```
async def test_get_session(mocker, mock_multi)
    mocker.patch("tornodo.gen.tornodo.gen.multi", return_value = [[],[],[],[],[]])
    session = get_session_detals(request_param, docs)
    assert session[0][session] is None
```

mocker is availble in pytest-mock,
https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

Comment: it's not mocking, again I am getting the same error message only.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to use tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase and gen_test to test async code:

```
# unit test
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase, gen_test

import mock
from your_file import get_session_details

class ExampleTest(AsyncTestCase):
    @gen_test
    def test_get_session_details(self):
        yield get_session_details(None, [])
```

Second, if you want to mock a async function, try this:

```
# unit test
import asyncio
import mock

from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase, gen_test

from your_file import get_session_details

def get_fake_future(return_value: Any = None) -> asyncio.Future:
    """Make a Future object with a expected return value.

    Args:
        return_value (any): the result of the future
    """
    fake_future = asyncio.Future()
    fake_future.set_result(return_value)
    return fake_future

class ExampleTest(AsyncTestCase):
    @mock.patch("your_file.multi", return_value=get_fake_future())
    @gen_test
    def test_get_session_details(self):
        yield get_session_details(None, [])
```